# Why do rspec doubles receive :== twice

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a test I'm working with that is unexpectedly failing. It is saying that == gets called on the double twice. Is it because it's an argument to the method too?

This is a distilled example of what I'm talking about

```
require 'rspec'
describe 'rspec test doubles' do
    let(:a_double) { double('a_double') }

    it 'should only call == once' do
        expect(a_double).to receive(:==).and_return(true)
        a_double == a_double
    end
end
```

And this is what I get when I run this test

```
F

Failures:

  1) rspec test doubles should only call == once
     Failure/Error: expect(watir_driver).to receive(:==).and_return(true)
       (Double "watir_driver").==(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 2 times with any arguments
     # ./double_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.019 seconds (files took 0.26902 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./double_spec.rb:6 # rspec test doubles should only call == once
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `TestDouble` class in `rspec-mocks`, we find this:

```
# This allows for comparing the mock to other objects that proxy such as
# ActiveRecords belongs_to proxy objects. By making the other object run
# the comparison, we're sure the call gets delegated to the proxy
# target.
def ==(other)
  other == __mock_proxy
end
```

So it looks like rspec purposefully reverses the call. Pretend you had two separate doubles, doing `double_1 == double2` would do something along these lines:

- Call `double_1 == double2`
- As we saw, this would then reverse it, but it would swap out `double_1` with `double_1`'s proxy: `double2 == __mock_proxy`
- Then `double2` would reverse the call yet again (with `other` being `double_1`'s proxy): `other == __mock_proxy`.
- Because `other` is a `Proxy` object instead of a `TestDouble`, a different `==` method is called (which at this point is comparing two `Proxy` objects), and we finally get the comparison.

So as you can see, `==` actually gets called on 3 separate things: the first double, the second double, and finally the first double's proxy. Because your first and second double are the same, it gets called twice.

See [`TestDouble`'s `==` method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/test_double.rb#L36) and [`Proxy`'s `==` method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/proxy.rb#L6)

Comment: Do you know when they started behaving that way? It looks like rspec 3.0 didn't

Comment: @DaneAndersen I'm not sure. I'm surprised it didn't in 3.0 -- that definition of `==` has been in place for almost 3 years now, and looking at the code for 3.0, it still does the `other == __mock_proxy` thing.